# Can Jager's ADS hurt people?

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

When Jager places his ADS sometimes he says "Stay out of the ADS line of fire" so I was wondering if Jagers ADS can do damage to deployables / players and how much damage it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my own knowledge, it does not do any damage to you or any other gadgets on your team. The physical device can do no damage and the action of shooting down ordinance (grenades etc) does not cause damage. You could sit directly in front of the ADS and it won't hurt you.

Although there is a chance that you end up blocking a grenade with your body or a shield and cause the ADS to not proc, potentially hurting yourself.

There's also a [thread on steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/359550/discussions/0/1621724915796990188/) that had this discussion a while ago, it still holds true as I said.

Note: Like many other deployable gadgets, it can be destroyed by things such as electricity (bandit wires or Kaid), gunfire, or grenades.